# Парсинг string в int

Tags: java

Есть код, который читает строку и парсит в `int`. Как заставить видеть переменную `s` как `int`?

```
line0 = line0;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\S?\\d*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line0);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String s = matcher.group(0);
    if (s.replaceAll("\\D", " ").length() == s.length()) {
        try {
            integers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }
}

int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
DaoImpl dao = new DaoImpl();
dao.save(i, line1, line2);
```

Получаю:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "79827956841"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.app.sms.reader.impl.SimpleSmsReader.smsReader(SimpleSmsReader.java:109)
at com.app.sms.reader.impl.SimpleSmsReader.readSms(SimpleSmsReader.java:51)
at com.app.workflow.impl.SimpleSmsWorkflow.processSms(SimpleSmsWorkflow.java:29)
at com.app.starter.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Comment: Оно не влезает в int, используйте long

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка возникает у Вас потому, что число `"79827956841"` не умещается в тип `int`.

Я попробовал вставить его в `Integer.parseInt()` без кавычек (как целое число) и получил следующую ошибку:

```
error: integer number too large: 79827956841
       System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(79827956841));
```

Могу посоветовать Вам использовать тип `long`.

P. S. Как я понял из Вашего стэк-трейса, число `79827956841` - телефонный номер. В таком случае, возможно, хранить номер в виде числа - не лучшая идея, так как чаще всего над номерами необходимо выполнять именно строковые операции. Ну, по крайней мере, я всегда работал с номерами как со строками. Конечно, я не отрицаю, что хранение в виде числа куда экономнее, так что, если у Вас подобный ход обусловлен именно экономией при хранении, прошу простить.

Comment: Номер нужен не string для последующей работы с ним. Вроде как чорного списка телефонных номеров.

Answer (score 0):

Число `79827956841` не помещается в знаковое 32 битное (`-2 147 483 648` - `2 147 483 647`)

Если вам нужно работать с такими большими числами используйте класс `Long` и соответственно метод `Long.parseLong()`. Допустимый диапазон значений от -2<sup>63</sup> до 2<sup>63</sup>-1