# Выбивает NumberFormatExeption при конвертации String в int

Tags: java, консоль

Нужно вытащить числа из файла для дальнейшей обработки, но при попытке конвертации строки в int выбивает исключение. Вот отрывок кода:

```
Scanner lines = new Scanner("./A.txt");

while(lines.hasNextLine()){
    String a = lines.nextLine();
    int crnt = Integer.valueOf(a);
```

Исключение следующее:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "./A.txt"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:654)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:999)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

В чём может быть проблема?

В фото более подробно приведены код и содержимое файла:
[image: Код и исключение]

[image: Содержимое файла]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: В считываемую строку случайно не попадает "\n" ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсинг string в int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1047599/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-string-%d0%b2-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код `Scanner lines = new Scanner("./A.txt");` сканирует **строку**, а не файл с названием `A.txt`, соответственно, никаких чисел в данном вводе не содержится.

Исправьте на:
`Scanner lines = new Scanner(new File("./A.txt"));`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Могу вас попросить, где можно подробнее с подобными нюансами ознакомится?

Comment: Внимательнее читайте ошибки компилятора и проверяйте [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-)